# No me deja crear esta FK

Tags: php, mysql

No me deja crear esta FK De esta PK; dice formato incorrecto

> ## 1005 - No puedo crear tabla `casasrurales`.`alojamientos` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalles…)

```
 //creación de la tabla
            $sql=" CREATE TABLE Clientes (
                ID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT ,
                Nombres varchar(25) NOT NULL,
                Apellidos varchar(25)NOT NULL,
                DNI varchar(9) NOT NULL,
                numPersonas int,
                localidadOrigen varchar(25),
                tarjetaCredito varchar(16) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (ID)
            )";

                if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
                    echo "table created";

                }else{
                    echo "table failed or created";
                }
                $sql=" CREATE TABLE alojamientos (
                    localizacion int NOT NULL,
                    numeroHabitaciones int,
                    incluidaMediaPension boolean,
                    fumador boolean,
                    ninios boolean,
                    mascotas boolean,
                    fechaEntrada date,
                    fechaSalida date,
                    ID int,
                    PRIMARY KEY (localizacion,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida),
                    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Clientes(ID)

                )";
    
                    if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
                        echo "table created";
    
                    }else{
                        echo "table failed or created";
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quizás no te deja crear la tabla, no porque la `FK` esté mal formada, sino porque estas intentado relacionar campos de distinto tipo. Debes poner tu campo `ID` de la tabla **alojamiento** del mismo tipo que el `ID` de la tabla **Clientes**.

Prueba a ponerlo así:

```
$sql=" CREATE TABLE alojamientos (
              localizacion int NOT NULL,
              numeroHabitaciones int,
              incluidaMediaPension boolean,
              fumador boolean,
              ninios boolean,
              mascotas boolean,
              fechaEntrada date,
              fechaSalida date,
              ID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, /*Mismo tipo que ID de la tabla Cliente*/
              PRIMARY KEY (localizacion,fechaEntrada,fechaSalida),
              FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Clientes(ID)
      )";
```